# two different css styles in one paragraph

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

In my spare time I am trying to create a startup. But not familiar with php. When customising code I came across the following problem:

I just want to add the echo "Including shipping" behind the price of a product on my page. But now the "including shipping" echo is getting the css from class="price" applied, I would like my custom echo to be a normal paragraph and keep the class="price" to the price. The two have to stay behind each other.

Code looks like this:

```
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> <?php $customshippingtext = " Including shipping "; echo $customshippingtext;  ?> </p>
```

Guessing it is really easy and wishing I had the time to dive into php cause I would probably be able to figure it out. Just need a quick solution for now..

Huge thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Brum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a span within the p tag with another class, like this:

```
<p class="price"><span class="another-class"> </span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo span as well, with custom class, and than in css style it as you like.

```
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> <?php $customshippingtext = " Including shipping "; echo '<span class="othertxt">'.$customshippingtext.'</span>';  ?> </p>
```

Or you can style it right way with inline styling

```
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> <?php $customshippingtext = " Including shipping "; echo '<span class="othertxt" style="color: black;">'.$customshippingtext.'</span>';  ?> </p>
```

Comment: Span funtion did the job, big thanks for the answers!